# TeamCity REST API how to get builds which aren't history builds

Tags: rest, api, teamcity

How to obtain builds which haven't got "History" value in "Changes" column in Overview. Now I use this url: `http://myteamcity/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:Project_Id,branch:feature_1&fields=count,build(buildType(id,name,projectName),number,id,changes(change(date,id,version,username,comment)),status,comment,revisions(revision))`. Is any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locator supports `history` property, so you can simply use `history:false` in your request to filted the history builds out, e.g.

```
http://myteamcity/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:Project_Id,history:false
```

Comment: It works. I wonder why commits from default branch cause history build on  my new branch.

Comment: @j.arap I'm not quitting getting your question; do you mean you have a build with some change from your default branch and then you trigger another one in different branch (selecting the same change from their common history)? Then (for example in git) it's the same change representing the same repo state and it seems ok to display new build as "history" one.

Comment: Suppose that I opened new branch - feature_1, on default branch. Then commits from default (which were builded on default before feature_1 was created), were builded on feature_1 as history build. I don't know why. This changes were added to default and were builded, so why they are history builds in feature_1?

Comment: Might be a bug, create an issue in TeamCity [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW) and provide details required to reproduce the issue (versions, screenshots etc)

Comment: I noted that commits are mirrored. Suppose that I marge my default branch with feature_1 branch. Then I switch to feature_1 and add new commit - "something". After that  build with change "something" occurs on feature_1 and default branches - on feature_1 as change on feature_1 and on default as change on default. I added it after marge so I don't know why it exists simultaneously on default and feature_1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use PowerShell(or something else) to request all(or top 10 for example) of builds in current build configuration, then examine ones who without changes.